# Formula with custom script doesn't update in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have some trouble with a spreadsheet: as said in the title, I put in a column a formula which is calling a custom script based on the value of another cell, but when I modify this other cell, the formula does not update... This seems to work with standard formulas, but, in my cell calling my script:

- If I try to add a blank in the fomula cell, the result is still not updated.
- If I clear the formula cell, and re-type the formula, it's still showing the old value.
- If I copy paste the formula cell in another one, the new cell is up-to-date.

Here is my script. If few words: for given 'company' parameter, it search for all rows matching this criterion and store the 3rd column cell in a variable, finally returned ( so return the last value ):

```
function getLastStatut(company) {
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();

  var out = "not found";
  var row;
  for(i in values){
    row = values[i];
    if(row[1]==company){
      out = row[2];
    }
  }
  return out;
}
```

And for example:

- A1 : Date
- A2 : Test
- A3 : Running
- A4 : =getLastStatut(B1)

So A4 display "Running", but if I change A3, it still shows "Running", whereas it should display the value of A3.

Is this a bug or is there something I'm doing wrong? Any help is welcome.

Alexis

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is with the caching "feature" for custom functions. I explain it in this [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022984/google-apps-script-to-summarise-data-not-updating/9023954#9023954), please read.

But the bottom line here is, a custom function should not access data that is not static, all variable information should be passed as parameter. In your case, the whole data set should be a parameter of your script. Custom functions should never get any range at all.

```js
//getting values like this is wrong (for a custom function)
var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
```

Comment: Thanks Henrique, it's a shame i didn't find the link you gave. I finally changed my function definition to have: 'function getLastStatus(company,values)' and call it this way '=getLastStatut(B19,A:C)' as I only need to parse the first three columns.

Comment: Sometimes it's difficult to come up with a good search criteria. Specially when we're not sure what the problem is :)