# How to improve App Scripts to SUM value of a column if its not strikethrough?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I want to SUM a column in Google Sheet only values which are not strikethrough.

I got this script from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12366667/sumif-not-strikethrough):

```
function SumIfNotStrikeThrough(rangeA1Notation)
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var mysheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var dataRange = mysheet.getDataRange();
  var mydatarange = mysheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation);
  var numRows = mydatarange.getLastRow();
  var rowindex = mydatarange.getRowIndex();
  var columnindex = mydatarange.getColumnIndex();
  
  var total =0;
  
  for(i=rowindex;i<=numRows;i++)
  {
    if(dataRange.offset(i-1, columnindex-1, 1, 1).isBlank() != true && dataRange.offset(i-1, columnindex-1, 1, 1).getFontLine() != "line-through")
    {
      var temp = dataRange.offset(i-1, columnindex-1, 1, 1).getValue();
      total = total + temp;
    }    
  }
  
  return total;
}
```

But it seems lazy and won't refresh if I change column/strikethrough on it (seems I need to reprocess it every time from scratch?).

What's the correct way on doint this? Any other "tricks" in Google Sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an onChange(e) trigger that will do what you want.  I don't know where you want the results so I just put it in E1.

You need to create an on change trigger.

```
function onChange(e) {
  try {
    console.log(e.changeType);
    if( e.changeType !== "FORMAT" ) return;
    let spread = e.source;
    let activeSheet = spread.getActiveSheet();
    console.log(activeSheet.getName());
    if( activeSheet.getName() !== "Test" ) return;
    let range = activeSheet.getRange("D2:D14");
    let total = sumIfStrinkThrough(range);
    console.log(total);
    range = activeSheet.getRange("A2:A14");
    total = total - sumIfStrinkThrough(range);
    // I put the result in cell E1
    activeSheet.getRange("E1").setValue(total);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

function sumIfStrinkThrough(range) {
  try {
    let total = 0;
    let values = range.getValues();
    let fontLines = range.getFontLines();

    values.forEach( (row,index) => {
        if( fontLines[index][0] != "line-through") {
          total = total+row[0];
        }
      }
    );

    return total;
  }
  catch(err)
  {
    throw "Error in sumIfStrikeThrough: "+err;
  }
}
```

Refernce

- [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

Comment: Still doesn't update automatically when I set a cell strikethrough. I need to copy/paste the formula to be recalculated...

Comment: There are no triggers that can detect a change in format like strikethrough.  You could put a button on the sheet to run the script after you manually make the change, or a custom menu.

Comment: Another way without script?

Comment: You could try an `onChange(e)` trigger.  Event object `e.changeType === "FORMAT"` will occur if you perform strikethrough.  But it will also occur when you `"EDIT"` and others..

Comment: Can you write down an example?

Comment: any news about the example?

Comment: You are using a custom function where the `rangeA1Notation` can be passed as a parameter.  You can't do that with an `onChange(e)` event but you could get the range from another cell.  So the event object is the only parameter to the function but you can immediately `getRange("A1")` where A1 contains the range as a sting.

Comment: I don't think this will work so. Question: can I value a cell (which could be hidden) with 1 or 0 when I format strikethrough on/off? This way I can just sum cell when the hidden cell is 1: possible solution? How would you do that?

Comment: I don't think so.  You want a trigger that will fire automatically when you change the format.  The `onChange(e)` is the only one that comes close.  But you also want to pass the `rangeA1Notation`.  You just can't do both.

Comment: Maybe if you explained how your custom function is incorporated into a sheet I could help figure out a solution.  Does this custum function occur in multiple cells with various range parameters?

Comment: Heres how I'm using It, on a single cell (which is what I Just Need) =SumIfNotStrikeThrough("D2:D14")-SumIfNotStrikeThrough("A2:A14"). But I need It Dynamic: every time i strike a Cell, It must do the calc

Comment: What do you mean with "You need to create an on change trigger."? Will this be valid for all files? Not very elegant: should be piloted within the sheet, not outside (imo)

Comment: [Installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: It becomes to much complicated for such basic task. I think I need to change paradigm. What's my option on sum cell except a specific constraints? For example: I could just color the cell instead of strikethrough; or maybe fill a hidden column with some specific value (i.e. 1/0) and than sum multiply the hidden column? Of course the value must be inserted automatically from the main ceil... any other strategies you can think of?

Answer (score -1):

Sum All Columns non strike through values

```
function sumNonStrikeThroughColumns() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const [h, ...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const [, ...fl] = sh.getDataRange().getFontLines();
  const sob = vs.reduce((a, r, i) => {
    r.forEach((c, j) => {
      if (i == 0) {
        a.pA.push(h[j]);
        a[h[j]] = 0;
      }
      a[h[j]] += (fl[i][j] == "line-through") ? 0 : c;
    })
    return a;
  }, { pA: [] })
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(sob));
  sob.pA.forEach(p => {
    Logger.log(`${p}: ${sob[p]}`)
  })
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't update automatically when I set a cell strikethrough. I need to copy/paste the formula to be recalculated...

Comment: Strike through does not generate an edit trigger.  This is it.

Comment: Another way without script?

Comment: The only other way I know of is polling and to get even close to a reasonable speed would require a timeout or interval timer running from a sidebar, but it can be messy  and difficult to setup. Personally, I avoid the use of onEdit whenever possible if you must have automatic response purchase Excel.  Personally, I am quite happy to make my edits and push a button and employers that require other than that can find someone else to work for them. I have found onEdit to be quite slow and unreliable.  Users have to be patient.

Comment: Cooper would onChange be an option as suggested on the other reply?

Comment: I don't get any change for a strike through but maybe it's just not working today.  Evidently, Google has had some problems today.