# Correct Syntax for OnEdit Trigger

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get an app that somebody else wrote to call the function each time the spreadsheet is edited.  I've been looking at the google developers website https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers and have tried a number of different options for syntax, but none of them have worked so far.  Here's the function as it stands (I haven't included any of the syntax options I tried, just the function itself named 'onEdit').  All I want this function to do is count the number of cells with a non-white background in the specified range and update the count displayed in the cell that uses this add-on script when the spreadsheet is edited.  Incidentally, does anyone know whether changing the background color of a cell counts as editing the spreadsheet?  Thank you.

```
function onEdit(range) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();



  var r = sheet.getRange(range);
  var i = 0;
  var colors  = r.getBackgroundColors();

  for(c in colors) {

    if(colors[c] != "white") {
      i++;
    }
  }

  return i;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

`onEdit` is an event handler. you wont be able to return something from it. just initialise `i` outside, i.e., to the global scope.

```
var i = 0;    
function onEdit(range) {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();



      var r = sheet.getRange(range);

      var colors  = r.getBackgroundColors();

      for(c in colors) {

        if(colors[c] != "white") {
          i++;
        }
      }


    }
```

Comment: I tried this solution but the returned value still doesn't update when the spreadsheet is edited.  Thank you.

Comment: I have removed the return value from the function as you can see. use `i` directly as the changes in `i` will retain in the global scope.

Comment: Thanks.  How would I go about using i directly?  As it is, this function produces a blank cell.  Also, should I change the function name from onEdit to something else now that I'm not trying to use that trigger?

Comment: Read the docs about how to use apps script in general for modifying a spreadsheet, then read about onEdit examples. As is, your code will do nothing.