# How to Get the currently selected cell/range?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, selection

Is there a way to get the identification (i.e. A1 notation) of a selected cell or range in Google Sheets?

Something like:

```
=SELECTION(['Sheet1']) -> "D6"
```

Comment: use getActiveRange() you can read about it [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactiverange)

Comment: Do you mean as a function in the spreadsheet, or by use of [tag:google-apps-script]?

Comment: I meant a spreadsheet function. I wanted to bring some interactivity to the sheet, so it would react to cell selection change. (Range not included). Last time I checked, that's was not possible.

Answer (score 23):

This custom function will get the selection at the time you update the cell with the function. But it will not update as the selection changes.

Henrique provides a good explanation of why custom functions like this don't update in [Google Apps - script to summarise data not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022984/google-apps-script-to-summarise-data-not-updating/9023954#9023954).

```
/**
 * A function that gets the current selection, in A1Notation.
 *
 * @customfunction
 */
function SELECTED_RANGE() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveRange().getA1Notation();
}
```