# How to get the currently selected cell/range with the Google Sheets API?

Tags: api, google-sheets

Same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30779426/how-to-get-the-currently-selected-cell-range), but when using the Google API, not Google Apps Script. I use Java but an illustration in any language or REST would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

You cannot do that, since the spreadsheet itself doesn't have a selected range. A certain user may have selected a range, but that information is not available to the API (see [spreadsheet resource](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets) for further reference).

#### Explanation:

In Apps Script, [bound scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) get the special privilege of using methods (e.g. [getActiveRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getactiverange)) that provide information on what the current user has selected (see [Special methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#special_methods)).

But even using Apps Script, this cannot work in [standalone scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone). Let alone using the API.