# Check column for formulas

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking to be able to check a range to ensure that all the cells in it have a formula; this would let me know if any cells in the column have been altered to static data. In other words, if any single cell in the range is NOT a formula, it should return FALSE.

I tried:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ISFORMULA(A1:A6))
```

but that still only checks the value in A1. Does anybody know how I could do this?

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/BQY3SBE-4tw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom function(see below). It needs a range as input (but as as a string) and a dummy value to bypass [caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022984/google-apps-script-to-summarise-data-not-updating), e.g.

```
=onlyFormulas("A1:A4", E1)
```

If you want to update the output, you need to change E1.

---

**Custom function**

```
function onlyFormulas(range, dummy) {
  var f = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(range).getFormulas();
  for (i = 0; i < f.length; i++)
    if (f[i] == '') {
      return false;
    }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to achieve this without scripts, but this is useful to get something up and running now. Thanks!

Comment: It's a bit of a hack but as far as I know there is no better solution at the moment.