# If i update data in Google Sheets my function do not update

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I know what wrong is in my program [Script to summarise data not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022984/script-to-summarise-data-not-updating/9023954#9023954) but I don't know how to fix this in my program

I making a Google Sheets list for my newsletter. I put data using FLOW XO using this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6W8mfgDq0eE but my situation is different because I equal to variables and deliver a score (result true/false) and if I want to post variables from FLOW XO my function has gon. How can I repair this?

jeżeli=if
licz.jeżeli=count.if

Link for my project:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MiS0362mUWoylryiNWkSnIDPhrMofTv6suqqcerQlfI/edit?usp=sharing

[image: my sheets]

Comment: [Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MiS0362mUWoylryiNWkSnIDPhrMofTv6suqqcerQlfI/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Just in case I am not the only person on SO who doesn't speak Polish, `JEŻELI(B2=H2;"PRAWDA";"FAŁSZ")` translates as `IF (B2 = H2, "TRUE", "FALSE")`.

Comment: Update: `LICZ.JEŻELI(N2:Q2;"PRAWDA")=4` => `COUNTIF (N2:Q2; "TRUE") = 4`

Comment: What is the exact nature of your problem? Your explanation, screenshot and spreadsheet don't really explain the problem that you have. In your spreadsheet you have two ranges "What I want"(A2:S4) and "What I have"(A15:S17). The data in the ranges UKeyword and TKeyword is identical - `exact() returns "true"`. The 'FAŁSZ' values in "What I have" render 'PRAWDA' when they are replaced with the formula. Would you please describe the problem in more detail.